# Installing Firebase package in Python

Tags: python, pip

When I try to install the firebase package in python using:

python -m pip install firebase

I get the output:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement firebase (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for firebase

Can't seem to find a solution for windows devices.

Comment: `firebase` does not exist, so you can't install it. Check on pypi.org (search for firebase and choose one of the results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `python -m pip install python-firebase`

Additional info: https://pypi.org/project/python-firebase/